# Angular 2 - Multiplication between inputs

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like the third input to appear to multiply the inputs `qtd` and `valueMoney`.

But since I am using the `mask-money directive` it is not possible to multiply, since I would need to convert the `valueMoney` to float.

And `valueMoney` currently has the `$` and `.` characters.

Would anyone have a solution to this problem?

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="qtd"/>

<input
    mask-money
    [(ngModel)]="valueMoney"
    [(moneyModel)]="moneyValue"
    [money-mask-options]="{ prefix: '$ ', thousands: ',', decimal: '.' }" />

<input type="text" [ngModel]="qtd*valueMoney" disabled />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to readme of ng2-mask-money at https://github.com/castrolol/ng2-mask-money,

- `ngModel` will get/set the value with text (example: '$ 1,234.56') ;
- `moneyModel` will get/set the number value (example: 1234.56);

So assuming you have your number value in `moneyValue`, use that instead of `valueMoney`, like this:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="qtd*moneyValue" disabled />
```

Comment: Did not work with `moneyModel` does not bring any results. I swapped by `ng2-currency-mask` library and it worked perfectly.